# Why Does This Compile: let v = UIView()

Tags: swift4.2, xcode10.1

The documentation for UIView lists two initializers:

> init(frame: CGRect)
>   init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

According to my understanding, the compiler should force me to use one of those two. So, what gives? UIView is "special"?

Comment: UIView inherits from NSObject which has init().

Comment: Mike If a class defines an initializer then initializer inheritance is blocked, yes?

Comment: I don't know about blocked initializer inheritance. It might be different in Objective-C with things that inherit from NSObject. I wasn't certain which is why I offered a comment instead of an answer. :)

Comment: Check out "Automatic Initializer Inheritance" here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html